# Importing mysql procedures generated from mysqldump --routines

Tags: stored-procedures, mysql

I use the mysqldump tool to make copies of my database.  The problem is, when I use the --routines parameter to output my stored procedures along with my data, the generated output causes an error when I try to import it.

It goes something like this:

```
% mysqldump --routines MyDB | mysql MyDB2
```

(where MyDB2 already exists but is empty)

The error I get is the following:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 307: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 23
```

Everything works correctly if I omit the --routines.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: What is version of target MySQL server? Does it support stored routines? Can you show the script, or just part of it near the line 307?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get this to work by splitting it into two calls:

```
% mysqldump MyDB | mysql MyDB2
% mysqldump --routines --no-create-info --no-data --no-create-db --skip-opt MyDB | mysql MyDB2
```

Comment: I'm having similar issues, i have a linux DB that i'm moving over to windows and i have all types of error with --routines

Comment: I have the same problem and encountered the same solution, but I want someone who can tell me why this is the case and if its simply a mysql bug, if its acknowledged or not. Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I know, I had problems like these when importing a 5.0 dump into a 5.1 db. There is a slight incompatibility

Answer (score 3):

If something's erroring when running the queries in MyDB2, it's best to:

1. Run mysqldump to save the output to a saved file.
2. Run the file bit by bit, to identify which part has the problem.
3. Fix that bit.

I once had a problem like this where I was exporting from an old version of mysql and importing into a newer one, which had declared one of my column names a reserved word. Are your two databases on different servers running different versions of mysql? Or is there some other difference between the databases (e.g. character set)?